# Compare SIFT operator and MOPS operator

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sift, feature-descriptor

How do they make the descriptor rotation-invariant? And how do they make the descriptor illumination invariant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How do they make the descriptor rotation-invariant?*

This is explained by D. Lowe in the [original SIFT paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) (see Chapter 5. Orientation Assignment):

> By assigning a **consistent orientation** to each keypoint based on local image
>   properties, the keypoint descriptor can be represented relative to this
>   orientation and therefore achieve invariance to image rotation.

*How do they make the descriptor illumination invariant?*

Here again this is detailed in this paper (see Chapter 6.1. Descriptor Representation):

> [...] the feature vector is modified to reduce the effects of illumination
>   change. First, the vector is **normalized to unit length** [...] we reduce the
>   influence of large gradient magnitudes by **thresholding the values** [...] then
>   renormalizing to unit length

According to the [original paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70120/tr-2004-133.pdf), MOPS follows the same principles.